# How to efficiently manipulate dataframe

Tags: python, loops, dataframe

My goal:if the value is 2, set this cell and the one on next row with 0. If the value is 3, set this cell to 1 and set the one on next row to 0.
from :

1 1 1
0 2 3
1 1 1

to:

1 1 1
0 0 1
1 0 0

```
for i in range(0,len(dfnew)):
    for j in range(0,len(dfnew.columns)):

        if dfnew.iloc[i,j] == 2: 
            dfnew.iloc[i,j] = 0  
            dfnew.iloc[i+1, j] = 0 

        if dfnew.iloc[i,j] ==3:   
            dfnew.iloc[i+1,j] = 0 
            dfnew.iloc[i,j] = 1
```

The double nested 'for loop' works but it's very inefficient on a 1000*2000 Dataframe. Is there anyway to speed up this manipulation? Thank you!

Comment: Um, what's the logic here???

Comment: It doesn't sound like a data-frame is what you want here. How big of a data-frame are we talking about? What is your use-case? What is the bottom left cell `0` in your result?

Comment: its a 1000 * 2000 dataframe. most number is 1. 2 and 3 are event labels.

Comment: Why is the bottom left cell 0 in your result? Shouldn't the bottom row be `1 0 0`?

Comment: You are right... my mistake, sorry

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that using `np.where` to get the indices, then using `iloc` on those indices, will be faster than your loop. `iloc` based setting has significant overhead, but can set multiple things very quickly, however, setting individual elements incurs that overhead *many many* times. So try:

```
In [30]: df
Out[30]:
   0  1  2
0  1  1  1
1  0  2  3
2  1  1  1

In [31]: idx, idy = np.where(df == 2)

In [32]: df.iloc[idx, idy] = 0

In [33]: df.iloc[idx + 1, idy] = 0

In [34]: idx, idy = np.where(df == 3)

In [35]: df.iloc[idx, idy] = 1

In [36]: df.iloc[idx + 1, idy] = 0

In [37]: df
Out[37]:
   0  1  2
0  1  1  1
1  0  0  1
2  1  0  0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! . It works with value=2. but when df=3, the output have a lot of 0.. I don't know why this happened

Comment: @ZZZ the order matters, maybe you want to get `idx1, idy1 = np.where(df ==3)` and `idx2, idy2 = np.where(df == 2)` **before* you use `iloc` setting...